# How do you determine the multicast groups an Android 10 device has joined?

Tags: android, multicast, android-10.0, android-vpn-service

In Android 9 and below we read `/proc/net/igmp` to determine this in our VPN app.  Android 10, however, has understandably locked down the data in `/proc/net`.  ([see here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem))

Is there an "official" way to get the multicast groups a device has joined?  Or even any hacky unofficial ways via reflection, etc?